# BigQuery adjust table to eliminate duplicates with two co-dependant rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Table has two dimensions, I would like to clear duplicates based on two dimensions, so that only one pair would remain after adjustment. I believe it should be basic, since i'm new maybe someone could point me to the right direction?

```
select id, label 
from table1

unique_id         label   
        1          fast
        1     streaming
        1          fast
        2         issue
        2          fast
        2         other
        3         other
        3         other
        3         other
```

I would like to receive such table:

```
unique_id         label   
        1          fast
        1     streaming
        2         issue
        2          fast
        2         other
        3         other
```

Comment: Why does a column called `unique_id` have duplicates?

Comment: @GordonLinoff hmm, interesting question:))

Comment: @GordonLinoff its a unique string associated with that id passed to udf which creates duplicates, but I get your point :) in my case I will aggregate labels per unique id

Comment: @tagilas . . . There are probably better names, such as `user_id` or `session_id` or whatever it might be.

Comment: @GordonLinoff totally agree, newbie mistakes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct id, label 
from table1;
```